# Android phone (Kitkat) lists a lot of CAs

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, android

My Android phone (Kitkat) list a LOT of CA under setting->security->Trusted credential. Does it mean that anyone who has access to any one of those private keys of those CA(s) can monitor or do "Man in the Middle" attack on my phone when it communicates with the internet?

I assume one can monitor not just the browser in the phone, but also all encrypted https communication if any app uses https, correct?

Also, if I installed my own CA into the USER part of the phone, can I monitor all https encrypted communication between my phone and the app's server in the net?

I wouldn't mind knowing more details on what all the apps are talking to the server about me, especially when they are encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with access to the private key of one of these CAs ( or their subordonate CAs) may issue certificates that your phone will consider valid. But they cannot inspect or monitor communication encrypted with someone elses keys (i.e. other CA).

If you install your own CA certificate you can issue fake certificates for any site you want to, and for Instance use an intercepting proxy ( Such as Burpsuite  from portswigger or ZED attack proxy ) to man in the middle attack yourself and inspect the traffic with certificates your phone and most apps on the phone will accept as valid. (unless the app has utilized ssl/tls pinning)  Doing this is easy on an iphone and a bit more complicated on android, google around for intercepting proxy on android, or maybe someone using an android phone can give you some pointers.

Comment: Certificate Pinning is when you trust one certificate only or perhaps trust only certificates signed by your root certificate. In Android you can accomplish this by using a custom **TrustManager**. To learn more check the guide from Android developers site https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html